# Eye and Kron with two dimensional matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have a matrix `a` of dimension `r x c x 4 x 11`, where `r` and `c` are the rows and column of an image. When I take `test=a(1,1,:,:)` and run the following code:

```
test=reshape(test,[4,11]);
b_a=kron(eye(3),test);
```

I am getting the dimension of `b_a` as `12 x 33`. Whereas when I do

```
b_a=kron(eye(3),a);
```

the dimension is not `r x c x 12 x 33` rather it is something like `429 x 8580`. Kindly help me to correct the code so that I get the desired dimension i.e `r x c x 12 x 33`.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `b_a=kron(eye(3),test)`? I doubt this will work but you could try `b_a=kron(permute(eye(3),[3,4,1,2]),a)`

Comment: This command is not working. It is showing some matrix but it is not correct. What I want is for a single pixel (particular `r` and `c`), I have a matrix of `4 x 11`. Upon using `kron` and `eye`, I am getting `12 x 33` for that pixel. How should I do it for the entire image so that I have the dimension as `r x c 12 x 33`.

Comment: Have you tried using a loop?

Comment: I have uploaded the answer. Kindly have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `kron` already reshapes the matrices in its arguments and doesn't dim-check further (assumes 2D). From `kron.m` for full matrices we can see the problem:

```
[ma,na] = size(A);
[mb,nb] = size(B);

A = reshape(A,[1 ma 1 na]);
B = reshape(B,[mb 1 nb 1]);
K = reshape(bsxfun(@times,A,B),[ma*mb na*nb]);
```

The first `size` parts are the problematic ones (as is typical with matlab syntaxing). Here `nargout` is causing the trouble. Let's see

```
a = rand(10,5,4,11);
[ma,na] = size(a);
[ma,na,size(a)]
```

This will give

```
>> 10 220 10 5 4 11
```

which means `na` is just the product of the remaining dimensions. Because when the output arguments don't match the rule is

```
%   N > NDIMS(X), SIZE returns ones in the "extra" variables, i.e., outputs
%                 NDIMS(X)+1 through N.
%   N < NDIMS(X), MN contains the product of the sizes of dimensions N
%                 through NDIMS(X).
```

I have no idea why anybody would implement this but anyway I digress.

You can either loop as you have done already or just modify the kron function and make sure that the remaining dimensions are preserved during `kron`ing.